# Typings for native window objects

Tags: typescript, local-storage

I'm wandering deep into the typescripts woods and now I'm lost.

How can I use an object that is on window, for example `window.localStorage` and what is the type of it? Do I really need to write my own interface to get the correct type?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `dom` library. It contains interface for [`localStorage`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/e6685ab0d9c5253390ba94413e5ae980b6283852/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L9921). See the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). You can also specify the libraries in `tsconfig.json`.